# In the loop average computation

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, average

I want to compute the average of a set of number, which is constantly increasing. I guess it's simple, but I'm struggling here:

Let's say:

1st iteration:

m(i)=a+b/2

2nd iteration:

m(i+1)=a+b+c/3

ect ...

Is there a simple way to take advantage of the computation done in the previous iteration in the next one ?

Comment: Keep track of the sum $s_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$, and return $s_n/n$.

Comment: Yes, but that can only be done at the end, when n is known.

Comment: But $n$ is always known, it's increased by one at each step (keep track of $n$ too, of course)

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the problem correctly, you have a set of numbers, say n, and you want the average of that, then your set grows to n+1, and you'd like the new average.

One thing you could do is always hold the accumulator (sum) of your set of variables. That way, you'd only need to divide by n to return the mean. This doesn't really make sense for a small set of numbers, but if you had a million or more, then this would be vastly quicker - you'd only be talking about a single addition and division to complete the mean.

Your storage requirements are O(1), not O(n). Again, it depends on your set size

Comment: So, your answer made me think. I just have to get the current (sum), multiply it by the previous N, add the new value, and divide by N.

Thanks !

Comment: @SyfIllis You can do that, but the extra multiplication/division at each step will take more time and cumulate roundoff, so it's better to keep track of only the sum (and $n$), and divide only when necessary.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just run into this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227543/better-algorithm-to-find-average 

The algorithm suggested there seems better than what I did ;)